# 'movimiento' is used unintialized (en c)

Tags: c

Estoy tratando de hacer que mi personaje se mueva en una matriz, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es este: no puedo modificar las firmas de las 2 funciones principales que estoy usando, las cuales son exportadas directamente de un *archivo.h* (*kronos.h*) pero dentro de mi archivo donde codeo (*kronos.c*) puedo crear nuevas funciones para invocarlas dentro de las funciones principales.

No puedo modificar los movimientos de la firma de una funcion principal, porque en la firma de una de las funciones principales el parametro `char movimiento` (el que me genera problemas) no es un puntero. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo sin modificar la firma de la función? A continuación les dejo el código.

Les comparto mi código con la biblioteca que estoy usando...

*juego.c* donde esta el main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "kronos.h"

int main(){
    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));
    juego_t juego;
    char movimiento;
    inicializar_juego (&juego);
    imprimir_terreno(juego);
    realizar_jugada(&juego, movimiento);
    return 0;
}
```

Acá están las características de los registros que estoy tratando de modificar (se encuentran dentro del *archivo.h* llamado *kronos.h*):

```
typedef struct coordenada{
    int fila;
    int columna;
} coordenada_t; 

typedef struct personaje{
    bool poder_activado;
    bool tiene_supertraje;
    coordenada_t posicion;
    int movimientos;
    int movimientos_con_poder;
    int cuadrante_inicial;
} personaje_t;

typedef struct juego{
    personaje_t personajes [MAX_PERSONAJES];
    int tope_personajes;
    robot_t robots [MAX_ROBOTS];
    int tope_robots;
    coordenada_t pinzas [MAX_PINZAS];
    int tope_pinzas;
    supertraje_t supertrajes [MAX_SUPERTRAJES];
    int tope_supertraje;
    int longitud_laser;
    int id_personaje_actual;
} juego_t;
```

Ahora les dejo las 2 funciones principales junto a una función extra que invoco dentro de una de las funciones principales (en *kronos.c*) (no puedo modificar los parámetros de las funciones principales, porque así me lo pide el trabajo) donde codeo las funciones:

```
void imprimir_terreno(juego_t juego){
    char matriz[MAX_FILA][MAX_COLUMNA];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILA; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_FILA; j++){
            matriz[i][j] = ESPACIO_LIBRE;
        }
    }

    matriz[juego.personajes[0].posicion.fila] [juego.personajes[0].posicion.columna] = ELASTIC;
    matriz[juego.personajes[1].posicion.fila] [juego.personajes[1].posicion.columna] = VIOLETA;
    matriz[juego.personajes[2].posicion.fila] [juego.personajes[2].posicion.columna] = DASH;
    matriz[juego.personajes[3].posicion.fila] [juego.personajes[3].posicion.columna] = MR_INCREIBLE;
    matriz[juego.robots[0].posicion.fila][juego.robots[0].posicion.columna] = ROBOT;
    matriz[juego.robots[1].posicion.fila][juego.robots[1].posicion.columna] = ROBOT;
    matriz[juego.robots[2].posicion.fila][juego.robots[2].posicion.columna] = ROBOT;
    matriz[juego.robots[3].posicion.fila][juego.robots[3].posicion.columna] = ROBOT;
    matriz[juego.supertrajes[0].posicion.fila][juego.supertrajes[0].posicion.columna] = SUPERTRAJE;
    matriz[juego.supertrajes[1].posicion.fila][juego.supertrajes[1].posicion.columna] = SUPERTRAJE;
    matriz[juego.supertrajes[2].posicion.fila][juego.supertrajes[2].posicion.columna] = SUPERTRAJE;
    matriz[juego.supertrajes[3].posicion.fila][juego.supertrajes[3].posicion.columna] = SUPERTRAJE;


    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILA; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j + 1 < MAX_COLUMNA; j++){
            printf("%c", matriz[i][j]);
            if (j+1 == MAX_COLUMNA / 2){
                printf(" | ");
            }
        }
        printf("%c\n", matriz[i][MAX_COLUMNA-1]);
        if (i+1 == MAX_FILA / 2){
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLUMNA; j++){
                if (j == MAX_COLUMNA / 2){
                    printf (" + ");

                } else{
                    printf ("-");
                }
            }
            printf("-\n");
        }
    }   
}


void pedir_movimiento(char* movimiento){
    printf("Ingrese su proximo movimiento, recuerde que solo puede moverse con las teclas W (arriba), A (abajo), S (izquierda), D (derecha):\n");
    scanf(" %c", movimiento);
    while (*movimiento != ARRIBA || *movimiento != ABAJO || *movimiento != IZQUIERDA || *movimiento != DERECHA){
        printf("Tecla de movimiento invalida! SOLO puede moverse con las teclas W (arriba), A (abajo), S (izquierda), D (derecha)\n");
        printf("Ingrese su proximo movimiento:\n");
        scanf(" %c", movimiento);
    }
}

void realizar_jugada(juego_t* juego, char movimiento){

    int cantidad_movimientos = 1;
    int personaje_actual = (juego->id_personaje_actual) - 1;
    while (personaje_actual <= juego->tope_personajes && juego->personajes[personaje_actual].movimientos >= 0){
        pedir_movimiento(&movimiento);
        if (movimiento == DERECHA){
            juego->personajes[personaje_actual].posicion.columna += cantidad_movimientos;
        }
        if (movimiento == IZQUIERDA){
            juego->personajes[personaje_actual].posicion.columna -= cantidad_movimientos;
        }
        if (movimiento == ARRIBA){
            juego->personajes[personaje_actual].posicion.fila -= cantidad_movimientos;
        }
        if (movimiento == ABAJO){
            juego->personajes[personaje_actual].posicion.fila += cantidad_movimientos;
        }
        imprimir_terreno(*juego);
    }
    
}
```

Cuando digo "funciones principales" me refiero a las funciones `void imprimir_terreno` y `void realizar_jugada`, de ningún modo tengo que cambiar sus parámetros, pero puedo invocar las funciones que quiera dentro. **¿Cómo puedo hacer que se mueva (cambiar valores dentro de un struct) en estas condiciones?**

Answer (score 0):

El error que te dice es que le estas pasando el parametro movimiento sin haberlo iniciado anteriormente. Es decir cuando haces la llamada a la función realizar_jugada(&juego, movimiento), esta variable movimiento tendría que ser 'W', 'A', 'S' o 'D'.
Aparte, mirando un poco tu código creo que te falta declarar las constantes:

```
char ARRIBA = 'W';
char IZQUIERDA = 'A';
char ABAJO = 'S';
char DERECHA = 'D';
```